# Cannot update to 1511

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows keeps failing to update my Windows 10 version to version 1511.

According to [this forum post](http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/32626-kb3122947-1511-update-anybody-else-get-26.html) I should just run:

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\c4a1b8896ce9fbfea96c1ee6890d52a5\windows10.0-kb3122947-x64.cab
```

I did and got:

> An error occurred trying to open -
>   C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\c4a1b8896ce9fbfea96c1ee6890d52a5\windows10.0-kb3122947-x64.cab
>   Error: 0x80070003 Error: 3

The problem is that the directory C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\c4a1b8896ce9fbfea96c1ee6890d52a5\ does not even exist.

What should I do?

It seems that windows have been trying to update this since July.

But always fail.

So yea the update is 8 months old but the first time windows try to update this is in July 2016

[image]

The issue is not simply that the update "fails". The issue is that windows do not bother downloading the update at all.

I restart computer in safemode. Delete the content of C:\windows\softwaredistribution\download and try again.

This is the content of the folder now

[image]

I've heard I can download some ISO. I looked around and try to find where I can download ISO for 1511 and I can't find one. There are some similar questions but the link points to nonworking links
This link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 for example, simply shows empty screen on my screen.

Comment: where can I get version 1607 .iso

Comment: I had  a successful update on 7/19/2016. It seems that the update isn't downloaded at all. Which is very strange. How do I know why it isn't downloaded at all?

Comment: what command? should I run? The problem is not that the stuff don't get installed. It's not even downloaded

Comment: The link you mention has no powershell command

Comment: The answer with ISO also fails. I open the link in the answer and got a blank page. I tried what you said before replying

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem.

[image]

Notice that this is only a partial answer.

There are still many mystery, such as why the normal automatic update fails in the first place. Why the updates aren't even downloaded. That would be on another question. [Cannot update to 1511](https://superuser.com/questions/1110747/cannot-update-to-1511/1110835#1110835)

How did I do it?

First I look the web.

I forget the exact site but basically I downloaded a file named MediaCreationTool.exe

Make sure you download it from microsoft or something. If someone can put a link a legitimate version of the file I'll appreciate it. I simply have forgotten where exactly I found it.

Then I run the program and my computer restarts a few time and it sort of works.